# Celery + Redis tasks not working on docker

Tags: django, docker, redis, celery, docker-compose

I tried setting up docker for my Django app that has Celery and Redis(the setup is working when I try to run it normally, without docker) .
My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
db:
  image: postgres:latest
  env_file: docker-compose.env
redis:
  image: redis:latest
  command: redis-server
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
web:
  build: .
  command: dockerize -wait tcp://redis:6379 ./docker-web-entrypoint
  env_file: docker-compose.env
  volumes:
    - .:/project-spartan
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db:db
    - redis:redis
worker:
  build: .
  env_file: docker-compose.env
  command: dockerize -wait tcp://redis:6379 ./docker-worker-entrypoint
  volumes:
    - .:/project-spartan
  links:
    - db:db
    - redis:redis
```

Those script that are called are for running the server and celery.
docker-web-entrypoint:

```
cd spartan/

echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')" | python manage.py shell            
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

docker-worker-entrypoint:

```
cd spartan
celery worker -A config.celery -Q default -n default@%h
```

My settings file where the config for celery is made:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://192.168.99.100:6379/0'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://192.168.99.100:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Comment: What are those `dockerize` commands? Why aren't you running the commands that just start that component in your architecture?